# Please ignore the scary length of the proof! I only query two lines! (Brownian Motion Notation/ Doob's Theorem)

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

Please ignore the scary length of the proof! I only query two lines!

So, I have two questions about the following part of the theorem. It is a paper looking at Stochastic Partial Differential equations, and here is an effort to bound the noise term, which essentially an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. I am very new to working with noise, so I am unsure of the following

- What does $\beta (\gamma(T))$ mean? $\beta$ is described as a Brownian motion (I know what this is at least!), but I have no idea what this means in terms of an expression when it is applied to a function.
- Also, when mentioning Doob's Theorem, I was not too sure what occurred. I took it to mean Doob's decompostion theorem, but although I understand this intuitively, I cannot see how it is applied here.

[image]

Help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: maybe you could add equations (18) &  (19) and assumptions 1 to 5 so that we can understand in more dpeth the context.

Comment: For the first part with what is given here I would bet that it is simply a a time change from $T$ to $\gamma(T)$.

Comment: So assumption 1 is that the linear operator in our SPDE generates an analytic semigroup, and also we have that $||Au||_{L^2} \leq Me^{-\delta_1t}t^{-1}||u||_{L_2}$. Assumption 5 is just the nature of the noise, i.e. it takes the form for a cylindrical Wiener process.

Comment: well it appears to me that the second point should be related to Doob's inequality where $E[sup_{t\in [0,T]} B_t ^p ]^{1/p}\leq \frac{p}{1-p}E[B_T^{p}]^{1/p}=\frac{p}{1-p}T^{1/2}$ elevating to the p-th power apears to give the result letting $\frac{p}{1-p}$ to the constant and using the time change $\gamma(T)$ Regards

Comment: thank you, what do you mean by a time change from $T$ to $\gamma(T)$?

Comment: Just what it means ... seeing an BM as a function of time replacing t by f(t).

Comment: Right... do you have a resource that explains Doob's inequality? x

Comment: I am sure that you can google it yourself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76645/discussion-between-catherine-drysdale-and-thebridge).

Comment: Here is what's going on. Firstly, $\delta(T)$ is a decreasing as a function of $T$, therefore $\delta(T) \leq \delta(T_i)$ whenever $T \in [T_i,T_{i+1}]$. The second thing to note is [Doob's $L^p$ martingale inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality#Further_inequalities), which (since $\gamma(T)$ is increasing) implies that $$\Bbb E \bigg[\bigg|\sup_{T \in [T_i,T_{i+1}]} \beta(\gamma(T))\bigg|^p\bigg] \leq (p/(p-1))^p \Bbb E[ |\beta(\gamma(T_{i+1}))|^p] ,$$ which (since $\beta(\gamma(T)) \sim \gamma(T)^{1/2} N(0,1)$) is bounded by $C_p|\gamma(T_{i+1})|^{p/2}$

Comment: BTW, if you want to read about Doob's inequalities, see [Section 4 here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxoYW93dXByb2JhfGd4OjdlZjVjZmU0MGZiNDQ5MzE), specifically Theorem 4.7. You can also look at Chapter 2 of the book of Morters and Peres, for the continuous-time version. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Where does this come β(γ(T))∼γ(T)1/2N(0,1)) ?

Comment: It's because $\beta$ is Brownian motion (which has Gaussian marginals with variance proportional to time) and $\gamma(T)$ is a deterministic time.